# How to wait for a thread stop while other threads need to invoke

Tags: multithreading, invoke

I have the following problem:

I have 6 equal threads and a free main UI thread.. But the 6 threads are heavily invoking on the main thread to update its controls... The question is: How can I let the main thread stop one of the threads with a button and then continue the flow in the button, while the other threads are still able to invoke on the main thread? the other threads may not stop at any time.. I just want to stop one of the threads, and then continue the code in my flowchart.. while the other threads are not harmed of the thread stop..

I'm using VB.NET 2010 on a Core i7

Comment: usually ui-threadaccess is queued and you should not have any problems at all. where's the problem?

Comment: The application hangs and each thread has its next statement at me.invoke(...delegate...)  The thread definition is in a class which has a threadrunningflag as boolean. i set the flag to false in the main thread on the particular object of the class.. The main thread is waiting in 
do: application.doevents: loop until <object>.threadstoppedflag

Comment: It sounds like a **bad design**...but the DoEvents() in the loop should allow the Invoke() calls to resolve while waiting for the condition to be met.  Can you show some of the code?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bad design. You can have one that allows everything run smoothly without calling doevents.

Comment: The question was correctly  answered by Idle_mund. It was indeed a bad design. We were inexperienced with Multithreading at the moment of asking.